# Infinite sum equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, taylor-expansion

I have some doubts about the following question:

$$Find\ the\ value\ a\ for\ which\ \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } {e^{na}}= 2$$

What I tried to do to solve it:

I've noted that I can rewrite this as the following:

$$1 + \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } {e^{na}}= 2$$

Hence, I can derive that:

$${e^{a}} + {e^{2a}} + {e^{3a}} + .... + {e^{na}} = 1$$

But from here I don't really know what to do. I know this isn't a hard problem, maybe I need to study something I don't understand yet. Could you point out a way to solve this problem? I just need a direction / general tip of where to go.

Comment: Are you familiar with the geometric series?

Comment: What you need exactly?  are you need to find $a$?

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(e^a)}^n=\frac{1}{1-e^a}$ provided $|e^a|<1$.

Comment: Thanks. Looking into Geometric Series I've managed to solve it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$1+{e^{a}} + {e^{2a}} + {e^{3a}} + .... + {e^{na}} +\cdots= 2\\\times e^{a}\\
{e^{a}} + {e^{2a}} + {e^{3a}} + .... + {e^{na}}+e^{(n+1)a} +\cdots= 2e^a\\\underbrace{{e^{a}} + {e^{2a}} + {e^{3a}} + .... + {e^{na}}+e^{(n+1)a}+\cdots}_{1}=2e^a\\1=2e^a\\$$can you take over from here ?

Answer (score 2):

Let $b=e^a$.

$$1+b+b^2+b^3+\cdots=\frac1{1-b}=2.$$

Hence

$$b=\frac12,\\a=\log\frac12.$$